# asp.net response.redirect() in subdomain

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, response.redirect

I have a subdomain in this name (job.amez.co) and there is a master page inside my subdomain that contain some links and one of the links redirect me to a page (Logout.aspx)

```
 <div class="blockContent">
                    <span id="span"></span>
                    بەخێربێیت بەرێز:  <span id="wel" runat="server" style="font-weight: bold;"></span>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/Profile.aspx" runat="server">پرۆفایل</asp:HyperLink></div>
                    <br />
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl="~/jobs/Myjobs.aspx" runat="server">کارەکانم</asp:HyperLink></div>
                    <br />
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" NavigateUrl="~/LogOut.aspx" runat="server">چوونە دەرەوە</asp:HyperLink></div>
                    <br />
                </div>
```

and when ever I click on these links instead of taking me to `job.amez.co/LogOut.aspx` it takes me to `job.amez.co/job/LogOut.aspx`